# Using hosted services in existing net core app

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I want to do background jobs with queues for uploaded files procession. Currently I have net core application with the structure:
-API
-Entities
-Repositories
-Services

I was looking at this example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

and was wondering do I have to create this worker service if I want it to run in my application? Or Can I just add new service called `HostedService` and then in my API's startup class add 
`services.AddHostedService<HostedService>()` and that would be it? sorry for noob question, but I didn't find a lot of examples, so if you have any good resources I would appreciate them too.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to.

You can use it in console app and install Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package and add it with AddHostedService. For more information [here](https://thinkrethink.net/2018/08/02/hostbuilder-ihost-ihostedserice-console-application/).

In Mvc or api it should work out of the box.